# Comparing $_POST values to database fields

Tags: php, mysql

I'm pretty sure this code has something wrong with it:

```
$sql="select * from user where username={$_POST['username']}AND pwd=   {$_POST['password']}";

$r = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
if($r)
{ 
$_SESSION['loggedin']=true;

echo "Welcome". $_POST['username']; 
}
```

Comment: SQL. Injection. AND XSS...

Comment: SQL injection and password in plain text?

Comment: and what is your question by the way?

Comment: This is a very concise example of precisely what not to do. Three enormous hazards in five lines of code.

Comment: @tadman I agree. There should be an ability to post the _worst ideas of all time_ on SO.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is off topic and should be posted at [alt.se.coderev](http://codereview.stackexchane.com)

Comment: The only thing missing here is an `eval` statement and the *four horsemen* will be present.

Comment: not getting any error.

Comment: @Colin that would be closed as off topic, no?

Comment: @pd4627 The short answer is you're doing **everything** wrong. Please read Madra's answer.

Comment: @ColeJohnson Yes, it would be - if it were a post. I just wish we could _promote_ (or, technically, demote) posts to that list. On another note, @tadman, you mean that `eval('md5("{$_POST[\'password\']}")');` isn't the right way to hash passwords!? Man, I have been doing it wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you are exposed to SQL injection. Please learn about preapred statements.

Also, you apparently store passwords in plain-text. That's a security risk since if your database is exposed (due to SQL injection attack, for example, *cough cough*), all of your passwords could be compromised.

A few links:

- **[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)**
- **[Prepared Statements - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)**
- **[How do you use bcrypt for hashing passwords in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4795385/871050)**

Comment: The `mysqli` actually supports placeholders, so it should be easy to fix this part.

Comment: @tadman: The fact that it *supports* it helps. But you gotta use it, you know :)

Comment: And no amount of driver support for prepared statements will save this person's database passwords or XSS issues :D.

Comment: At least it does't require re-writing some horrible `mysql_query` based system.

Comment: Madara Uchiha is correct. Also you forgot to fetch the query.